# python dot operator in 'from import' statement

Tags: python, scipy

```
from . import _nd_image
```

My question is that there is no such file _nd_image.py in the current directory and code uses this above import statement and below, somewhere in code there is a statement `_nd_image.fun()`.

How is it possible to import a file which is not present in the directory and use it to call some function.

The code is taken from [here](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/scipy/scipy/ndimage/filters.py)

```
import statement in at line no.36
```

and usage of _nd_image is at line no. 143

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a file `_nd_image.pyd` or `_nd_image.so` in the directory.  This is a Python extension library written in C.  These files act as normal Python modules that can be imported.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262884/python-c-extension-use-extension-pyd-or-dll) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html) for more info.