# cannot import name '_nd_image' - SCIPY

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm having this problem:

> File "C:\IntelPython3\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\filters.py", line 37, in

```
from . import _nd_image
```

> ImportError: cannot import name '_nd_image'

I was checking in that path and i can't find any module or something called nd_image but i've looked for all the scipy releases and i can't find it too.

Can someone help please? (WINDOWS)

Comment: share the version of scikit-learn and python

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the older version of scipy with the latest version of python.
You should upgrade scipy to solve the problem by typing below command line.

`pip install --upgrade scipy`

If you are not using pip in Window, you can use conda or other things.

And actually, you can not find _nd_image.py module. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010579/python-dot-operator-in-from-import-statement) might be helpful.