# How to specify the dynamic library location when writing a setup file for python c-extension?

Tags: python, dll, python-c-api, fftw

I'm trying to write a c-extension for python and I'm using a library (FFTW) which has some dynamic library files (.dll). So I wrote some c code and also a *setup.py* file to install it and when I run the setup file everything goes well and my c-extensions will be installed successfully. But when I try to use my new module I will encounter the following error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

So I assume it is referring to the dll files of FFTW library. If I copy the dll files to my *C:/windows/system32* My code will run without any error. But I wish not to do that and instead have the dll files alongside my code.
According to [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#library-options) for writing the setup script:

> You can also specify the libraries to link against when building your
> extension, and the directories to search for those libraries. The
> *libraries* option is a list of libraries to link against, *library_dirs*
> is a list of directories to search for libraries at link-time, **and
> *runtime_library_dirs* is a list of directories to search for shared
> (dynamically loaded) libraries at run-time**.

But when I use the *runtime_library_dirs* option and try to install my extension by running the *setup.py* I will encounter the following error.

> warning: I don't know what to do with 'runtime_library_dirs':
> ['./c-extension/bin']
> error: don't know how to set runtime library
> search path for MSVC

I'm using python 3.6.

Here is a sample of my *setup.py* code:

```
import numpy
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

def main():
    setup(name="simple_ext",
          version="1.0.0",
          description="Python interface for the simple C extension library function",
          author="My Name",
          author_email="my_email@email.com",
          data_files=[('./c-extension/bin', ['libfftw3-3.dll','libfftw3l-3.dll','libfftw3f-3.dll'])],
          ext_modules=[Extension("simple_ext", ["simple_ext.cpp"],
                  include_dirs=[numpy.get_include(), './c-extension/include']),
                  runtime_library_dirs=['./c-extension/bin'],
                  library_dirs=['./c-extension/lib'],
                  libraries = ['libfftw3-3','libfftw3l-3','libfftw3f-3']])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So does anyone any idea what wrong and what should I do to fix it?

**Edit:**

So based on *Patrik Polakovic*'s comment I managed to somehow solve the problem. The thing is when I used *data_files* like this:

```
data_files=[('./c-extension/bin', ['libfftw3-3.dll','libfftw3l-3.dll','libfftw3f-3.dll'])],
```

There was an hidden error message that I had missed and apparently was ignored by the compiler too.

> error: can't copy 'libfftw3-3.dll': doesn't exist or not a regular
> file

But when I changed it to the form below:

```
data_files=[('', ['./c-extension/bin/libfftw3-3.dll','./c-extension/bin/libfftw3l-3.dll','./c-extension/bin/libfftw3f-3.dll'])],
```

the setup was able to locate my shared library files and the following message was also displayed:

> copying c-extension\bin\libfftw3-3.dll ->
> C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\newEnv\
>
> copying c-extension\bin\libfftw3l-3.dll ->
> C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\newEnv\
>
> copying c-extension\bin\libfftw3f-3.dll ->
> C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\newEnv\

So I can use this as a temporary solution. But I still don't know what's wrong with the first form of *data_files* option that I used (Which looks legit to me) and more importantly I don't understand what's wrong with using the *runtime_library_dirs* option.

Comment: I used *data_files* argument to my *setup* method. `data_files=[("lib/site-packages/mypkg", [get_dll_path()])],`. I don't know if this is correct approach but it did the job.

Comment: @PatrikPolakovic Thanks for sharing this info with me. I somehow managed to solve the problem using the data_files argument. But I'm still not sure what's wrong with using  the runtime_library_dirs argument. I updated the question.

Comment: very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62662816/5769463

Comment: The problem with `runtime_library_dirs` is that it translates to `rpath`, which exists only on Linux but not Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the link @ead. And you are right `runtime_library_dirs` does work on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, on Windows `runtime_library_dirs` does not work and will cause MSVC to error.

In your original question, you used `data_files` incorrectly, as from the [relevant part of the `setuptools` docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deprecated/distutils/setupscript.html) on writing the setup script, note the sentence

> Each *(directory, files)* pair in the sequence specifies the installation directory and the files to install there.

Your DLLs are located in `./c-extension/bin`, so you need to prepend that relative path to the names of each DLL. The following from the same page explains *directory* concisely:

> The *directory* should be a relative path. It is interpreted relative to the installation prefix (Python’s `sys.prefix` for system installations; `site.USER_BASE` for user installations).

That is, the files specified in *files* will be copied to `C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\newEnv\directory`. So passing `./c-extension/bin` to *directory* is also a mistake.