# Including and distributing third party libraries with a Python C extension

Tags: python, c, setuptools, python-c-api, python-extensions

I'm building a C Python extension which makes use of a "third party" library— in this case, one that I've built using a separate build process and toolchain. Call this library `libplumbus.dylib`.

Directory structure would be:

```
grumbo/
  include/
    plumbus.h
  lib/
    libplumbus.so
  grumbo.c
  setup.py
```

My `setup.py` looks approximately like:

```
from setuptools import Extension, setup

native_module = Extension(
    'grumbo',
    define_macros = [('MAJOR_VERSION', '1'),
                     ('MINOR_VERSION', '0')],
    sources       = ['grumbo.c'],
    include_dirs  = ['include'],
    libraries     = ['plumbus'],
    library_dirs  = ['lib'])


setup(
    name = 'grumbo',
    version = '1.0',
    ext_modules = [native_module] )
```

Since libplumbus is an external library, when I run `import grumbo` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/path/to/grumbo/grumbo.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: lib/libplumbus.dylib
  Referenced from: /path/to/grumbo/grumbo.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

**What's the simplest way to set things up so that `libplumbus` is included with the distribution** and properly loaded when `grumbo` is imported? (Note that this should work with a virtualenv).

I have tried adding `lib/libplumbus.dylib` to `package_data`, but this doesn't work, even if I add `-Wl,-rpath,@loader_path/grumbo/lib` to the Extension's `extra_link_args`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The goal of this post is to have a `setup.py` which would create a source distribution. That means after running

```
python setup.py sdist
```

the resulting `dist/grumbo-1.0.tar.gz` could be used for installation via

```
pip install grumbo-1.0.tar.gz
```

We will start for a `setup.py` for Linux/MacOS, but then tweak to make it work for Windows as well.

---

The first step is to get the additional data (includes/library) into the distribution. I'm not sure it is really impossible to add data for a module, but `setuptools` offers functionality to add data for packages, so let's make a package from your module (which is probably a good idea anyway).

The new structure of *package* `grumbo` looks as follows:

```
src/
  grumbo/
     __init__.py  # empty
     grumbo.c
     include/
       plumbus.h
     lib/
       libplumbus.so
setup.py
```

and changed `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages

native_module = Extension(
                name='grumbo.grumbo',
                sources = ["src/grumbo/grumbo.c"],
              )
kwargs = {
      'name' : 'grumbo',
      'version' : '1.0',
      'ext_modules' :  [native_module],
      'packages':find_packages(where='src'),
      'package_dir':{"": "src"},
}

setup(**kwargs)
```

It doesn't do much yet, but at least our package can be found by `setuptools`. The build fails, because the includes are missing.

Now let's add the needed includes from the `include`-folder to the distribution via `package-data`:

```
...
kwargs = {
      ...,
      'package_data' : { 'grumbo': ['include/*.h']},
}
...
```

With that our include-files are copied to the source distribution. However because it will be build "somewhere" we don't know yet, adding `include_dirs  = ['include']` to the `Extension` definition just doesn't cut it.

There must be a better way (and less brittle) to find the right include path, but that is what I came up with:

```
...
import os
import sys
import sysconfig
def path_to_build_folder():
    """Returns the name of a distutils build directory"""
    f = "{dirname}.{platform}-{version[0]}.{version[1]}"
    dir_name = f.format(dirname='lib',
                    platform=sysconfig.get_platform(),
                    version=sys.version_info)
    return os.path.join('build', dir_name, 'grumbo')

native_module = Extension(
                ...,
                include_dirs  = [os.path.join(path_to_build_folder(),'include')],
)
...
```

Now, the extension is built, but cannot be yet loaded because it is not linked against shared-object `libplumbus.so` and thus some symbols are unresolved.

Similar to the header files, we can add our library to the distribution:

```
kwargs = {
          ...,
          'package_data' : { 'grumbo': ['include/*.h', 'lib/*.so']},
}
...
```

and add the right lib-path for the linker:

```
...
native_module = Extension(
                ...
                libraries     = ['plumbus'],
                library_dirs  = [os.path.join(path_to_build_folder(), 'lib')],
              )
...
```

Now, we are almost there:

- the extension is built an put into  `site-packages/grumbo/`
- the extension depends on  `libplumbus.so` as can be seen with help of `ldd`
- `libplumbus.so` is put into `site-packages/grumbo/lib`

However, we still cannot import the extension, as `import grumbo.grumbo` leads to

> ImportError: libplumbus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such
> file or directory

because the loader cannot find the needed shared object which resides in the folder `.\lib` relative to our extension. We could use [`rpath`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8482152/5769463) to "help" the loader:

```
...
native_module = Extension(
                ...
                extra_link_args = ["-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN/lib/."],
              )
...
```

And now we are done:

```
>>> import grumbo.grumbo
# works!
```

Also building and installing a wheel should work:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

and then:

```
pip install grumbo-1.0-xxxx.whl
```

The first mile stone is achieved. Now we extend it, so it works other platforms as well.

---

**Same source distribution for Linux and Macos:**

To be able to install the same source distribution on Linux and MacOS, both versions of the shared library (for Linux and MacOS) must be present. An option is to add a suffix to the names of shared objects: e.g. having `libplumbus.linux.so` and `libplumbis.macos.so`. The right shared object can be picked in the `setup.py` depending on the platform:

```
...
import platform
def pick_library():
    my_system = platform.system()
    if my_system == 'Linux':
        return "plumbus.linux"
    if my_system == 'Darwin':
        return "plumbus.macos"
    if my_system == 'Windows':
        return "plumbus"
    raise ValueError("Unknown platform: " + my_system)

native_module = Extension(
                ...
                libraries     = [pick_library()],
                ...
              )
```

---

**Tweaking for Windows:**

On Windows, dynamic libraries are dlls and not shared objects, so there are some differences that need to be taken into account:

- when the C-extension is built, it needs `plumbus.lib`-file, which we need to put into the `lib`-subfolder.
- when the C-extension is loaded during the run time, it needs `plumbus.dll`-file.
- Windows has no notion of `rpath`, thus we need to put the dll right next to the extension, so it can be found (see also this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62662816/5769463) for more details).

That means the folder structure should be as follows:

```
src/
  grumbo/
     __init__.py
     grumbo.c
     plumbus.dll           # needed for Windows
     include/
       plumbus.h
     lib/
       libplumbus.linux.so # needed on Linux
       libplumbus.macos.so # needed on Macos
       plumbus.lib         # needed on Windows
setup.py
```

There are also some changes in the `setup.py`. First, extending the `package_data` so `dll` and `lib` are picked up:

```
...
kwargs = {
      ...
      'package_data' : { 'grumbo': ['include/*.h', 'lib/*.so',
                                    'lib/*.lib', '*.dll',      # for windows
                                   ]},
}
...
```

Second, `rpath` can only be used on Linux/MacOS, thus:

```
def get_extra_link_args():
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        return []
    else:
        return ["-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN/lib/."]
    

native_module = Extension(
                ...
                extra_link_args = get_extra_link_args(),
              )
```

That it!

---

The complete setup file (you might want to add macro-definition or similar, which I've skipped):

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension, find_packages

import os
import sys
import sysconfig
def path_to_build_folder():
    """Returns the name of a distutils build directory"""
    f = "{dirname}.{platform}-{version[0]}.{version[1]}"
    dir_name = f.format(dirname='lib',
                    platform=sysconfig.get_platform(),
                    version=sys.version_info)
    return os.path.join('build', dir_name, 'grumbo')


import platform
def pick_library():
    my_system = platform.system()
    if my_system == 'Linux':
        return "plumbus.linux"
    if my_system == 'Darwin':
        return "plumbus.macos"
    if my_system == 'Windows':
        return "plumbus"
    raise ValueError("Unknown platform: " + my_system)


def get_extra_link_args():
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        return []
    else:
        return ["-Wl,-rpath=$ORIGIN/lib/."]
    

native_module = Extension(
                name='grumbo.grumbo',
                sources = ["src/grumbo/grumbo.c"],
                include_dirs  = [os.path.join(path_to_build_folder(),'include')],
                libraries     = [pick_library()],
                library_dirs  = [os.path.join(path_to_build_folder(), 'lib')],
                extra_link_args = get_extra_link_args(),
              )
kwargs = {
      'name' : 'grumbo',
      'version' : '1.0',
      'ext_modules' :  [native_module],
      'packages':find_packages(where='src'),
      'package_dir':{"": "src"},
      'package_data' : { 'grumbo': ['include/*.h', 'lib/*.so',
                                    'lib/*.lib', '*.dll',      # for windows
                                   ]},
}

setup(**kwargs)
```

Comment: This answer was great! This path_to_build_folder() function shown isn't working for me with not work with `pip -e .` builds, so I added include_dir paths twice to include the location in the repo as well as the build folder path.