# Python C extension packaging DLL along with pyd

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, dll, python-c-api

My project exposes a static library (call it `static.lib`) to CPython (3.8) interpreter. It consists of a static library that is in turn dependent on a DLL FTDI driver. After reading [this thread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2014-September/024950.html) it appears that optimal solution to providing third party DLLs is to bundle them along with a Python package - to make sure that DLL is located in the same directory as `.pyd` binary.

The issues I am having is that after running `pip install .` for my package, the required DLL (call it `required.dll`) is placed in  `site-packages/package/required.dll` and the actual C extension library (call it `package.pyd`) is placed in `site-packages/package.pyd`.

Since it is not in the same directory when I attempt to use the library in Python I get

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing package: The specified module could not be found.
```

Below is my `setup.py`

```
setuptools.setup(
        name="package",
        version="1.0.0",
        packages=setuptools.find_packages(where="src"),
        package_dir={"": "src"},
        py_modules=[splitext(basename(path))[0] for path in glob("src/*.py")],
        use_scm_version=True,
        package_data={
            "package": [
                "_clibs/libs/required.dll",
            ],
        },
        ext_modules=[
            setuptools.Extension(
                "package",
                include_dirs=["src/package/_clibs/inc"],
                sources=[
                    "src/package/_clibs/src/api.cpp",
                    "src/package/_clibs/src/utils.cpp",
                ],
                library_dirs=[
                    "src/package/_clibs/libs",
                ],
                libraries=["static", "User32"],
                language="c++"
            ),
        ],
    )
```

Directory layout for the project is as follows:

```
/
setup.py
.tox
src/
...package/
......wrapper.py
......__init__.py
......_clibs/
.........inc/
.........src/
............api.cpp
............utils.cpp
.........libs/
............required.dll
............static.lib
```

I also use `tox` for virtual environment management.

The suggested answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63804883/including-and-distributing-third-party-libraries-with-a-python-c-extension) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62662816/how-do-i-use-the-correct-dll-files-to-enable-3rd-party-c-libraries-in-a-cython-c) outline a very similar `setup.py` and the same method of including the DLL - through `package_data` option. The answers seem to suggest that DLL and `.pyd` are then placed on the same level which does not happen for me. I can't quite place what it is I am missing to get the same behaviour.

```
python 3.8.6
setuptools 51.0.0
pip 20.3.1
```

TL;DR DLL is being placed in a different directory to `.pyd` binary thus making it invisible to Windows loader

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Including and distributing third party libraries with a Python C extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63804883/including-and-distributing-third-party-libraries-with-a-python-c-extension)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62662816/5769463

Comment: Those are great answers, however I still run into issues described in my original post. I have tried placing `required.dll` in different directories - same result. I will edit the answer to also include my package directory layout.

Comment: How does *PIP* know how to build *library.pyd*? I see no reference of it in *setup.py*.

Comment: @CristiFati `library.pyd` is the product of `setup.py`, replace `library.pyd` with whatever name ends up being assigned to the binary. To keep consistent with the script I provided  it should be `package.pyd` or some variant of thereof. Apologies for confusion, I tried to hide actual library names not relevant to this question, this is just an inconsistency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging, I found a way that worked for me. [This thread](https://bugs.python.org/issue36085) has shed light on the problems of DLL loading on Windows and most recent (Python 3.8) developments on the issue.

The solution I went with was borrowed from `numpy`.
In order to properly bundle DLLs along with your C extension:

1. Create a directory within your package that will contain all required DLLs your extension will be using
2. Modify your build procedure to include this directory along with `sdist` and wheel distributions
3. Once user imports your package, first thing you do is dynamically modify paths for where DLLs will be searched for (two different methods depending if you are on 3.8 or lower)

Roughly, adding `package_data` to your `setup.py` should do the trick (minus the shenanigans that come with MANIFEST files and using `package_data`, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distutils))

```
 package_data={"your package name": ["path_to_DLLs/*"]},
```

To implement #3, as an option in your `__init__.py` for the package add the following (taken 99% line by line from `numpy` `__config__.py` that gets auto-generated by their very complex build system.

```
import os
import sys

PATH_TO_DLL = "YOUR DLL DIRECTORY IN YOUR PACKAGE"
extra_dll_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), PATH_TO_DLL)

if sys.version_info >= (3, 8):
    os.add_dll_directory(extra_dll_dir)
else:
    # legacy DLL loading mechanism through PATH env variable manipulations
    os.environ.setdefault("PATH", "")
    os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + extra_dll_dir
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated. The thread linked to this ticket talks about the need for better documentation for C extension onboarding and I have not been able to find any. So far, C extensions + Windows + `setuptools` made for incredibly frustrating experience.