# Cython import module error on production machine

Tags: cython

I have compiled pyx codes using cython on my development machine which resulted in pyd files. `import mymodulename` works fine on my machine.
However, when I took my pyd files to production machine, `import mymodulename' is throwing error that module not found.

I have looked at [cython-pyd-files-not-importing-through-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392003/cython-pyd-files-not-importing-through-python), however not much help. Also, my development machine has python 3.7 and production machine has 3.8 . What else I should do to make this work?

Comment: The Python version you built it against __must__ match the Python version that runs it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. It was python version issue. Cython needs same python version on both machines. After installing python 3.8 on my local environment and compiling , the new pyd files started working on production machine also.